# How to read multiple objects in a file to an arraylist?

Tags: java, file, oop, object, arraylist

I'm trying to read all objects from a file and saving it to and array. But, I get a StreamCorruptedException. Another question: it is unrelated : Whenever I view the file with objects stored in it, it's in Object language. Is it possible to turn it to human readable language?

```
public void generateLibReport() throws IOException, FileNotFoundException, ClassNotFoundException{

    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new 
    FileInputStream("LibrarianFile.txt"));
    boolean check = true;
    ArrayList<Librarian> array = new ArrayList();
    while(check){
        try{
            Librarian librarian = (Librarian)ois.readObject();
            array.add((Librarian)librarian);
        }
        catch(EOFException e){
            for(Librarian l:array){
            System.out.println(l);
            }
            check = false;
            ois.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have two "unrelated" questions, why have you put them both in one post?

Comment: In the hopes that both questions can be answered in one post instead of 2. Also the second question is a general question to see if it is possible.

Comment: This _turn it to human readable language_ is possible if you serialize to a human readable language, like [XML](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/index.html) or [JSON](https://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-2-convert-java-object-to-from-json).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use readable language, try save objects in `JSON` format.

For example use `Gson` library.

```
void save(List<Librarian> libs) {
    String json = gson.toJson(libs);
    //save json text in simple text file
}

List<Librarian> load(String filename) {
    //read text file to json variable
    String json = ...;
    return gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<List<Librarian>>(){});
}
```

This way solve both questions.